# Understanding Firebase User Auth

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, user-data

I made a simple Angular + Firebase app, which you can [see here.](https://bookmark-it.firebaseapp.com)

I want to add user authentication to it using Firebase, and have successfully been able to create an account and login using Firebase's email and password auth.

The problem is, I don't know how to take the next step to separate each user's data — I want each user to only to be able to change their own data, and show nothing until they're logged in.

The only thing I could think of was to change the firebase URL I'm using to separate the FirebaseArrays I'm using, but that seems super hacky and didn't work when I tried it.

How am I supposed to use the unique uids to create separate, individual user data?

Comment: do you want to edit just the username and password for the user or do you want other details to be editable aswell

Comment: @gerdi I don't want to edit the username and password, I want to be able to have data specific to each user. So each user could log in, see and change their book list, and once they log out that data is unavailable. Sorry for not being clear in my initial question!

Answer (score 0):

So every user will have a unique id within the authorize table , of which you cannot directly access ( in that you cannot add tables - firebase keeps it locked down for security reasons )

This still allows for a separation based on the id. There will essentially be a books array, You could add an array of users on each book, but that could get redundant. I think the best solution would be to create a `user_books` array. This will list all the users by id that have books, with the bookID as a nested array

```
user_books
    -Jsdee23dnn23d2n3d
          |- sdfEDASED82342dsd : true
          |- SDEdsdfwer343dsdf : true  
    -Jsdeesdfffffs433
          |- 43334sdfsrfesrdfg : true
          |- sdfsf333fsdfsrrrr : true
```

This connects the books to the users. So each user has an array of books . This is the target to access when you want the user to perform CRUD operations

```
var usersRef = new Firebase('https://test.firebaseio-demo.com/user_books');
var ref = usersRef.child('userID');
```

When you create a book you will need to update both the `book` table and the `user_books` table with the selected user(s) associated to the book

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I should've specified more clearly: I want users to be able to change their own data, as in what books they are currently reading — I want them to be able to log in, see their _own_ book list (which was pulled from the database), and be able to change it.

I just don't know how to create a new section in my Firebase database for each user, and only interact with that section of the database for each individual user.

Comment: Updated. Not sure if this is more inline with the question. Not sure if i need to go into detail on code to create the actual arrays

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Would it be possible to lay out the data by having a highest-level `users` array with each individual user having three separate arrays for books (`want to read`, `reading`, `read`)? I suppose I'm having trouble figuring out how to get Firebase to properly manipulate data within the appropriate user's array after logging in.